# How to pass and get parameter with Router params in Angular 4.?

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to pass an id  with url using Router in Angular. And i have to fetch that value on another page. Like I have a student list. On click of edit button belongs to particular student on the list. The id of that student pass to edit student details page. After fetching that studentId I want show existing details in the input fields.

So How i can do this?

this is my example path

```
 { path: 'school-students-list', component: studentsListPageComponent },
  { path: 'edit-student-details', component: studentEdit },
```

Comment: `school-students-list/:id`??

Comment: @JaydipJadhav  yes . id should be passed like this in url. example:( school-students-list/:123)

Comment: @JaydipJadhav : how i can do this? and how to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Give the route a parameter like this:

```
{ path: 'edit-student-details/:id', component: studentEdit }
```

And then use `ActivatedRoute` in that component to access the route parameters. Import it from `@angular/router`

```
import { ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';
```

Inject this into the constructor

```
private routeSub: Subscription;

constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}
```

On init, subscribe to route parameters

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.routeSub = this.route.params.subscribe((params: Params): void => {
        const id = params['id'];
    });
}
```

Always a good idea to unsubscribe on destroy

```
ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.routeSub.unsubscribe();
}
```

And to link to this page, passing in their member ID, do this on your student listings page:

`<a [routerLink]="['/edit-student-details', memberId]">Edit</a>`

To navigate via a component method, inject `Router` from `@angular/router` and then when you want to navigate, use `this.router.navigate(['/edit-student-details', memberId]);`

Comment: I updated my answer with how to use `ActivatedRoute`

Comment: in my case the id is dynamic.. that is coming from api response and i assigned it in (memberId). so i can pass member id here or what?

Comment: When you navigate to let's say `/edit-student-details/1` the id then accessed through `ActivatedRoute`. Is that what you are trying to do? It's a bit unclear.

Comment: i'm having a student list page there i can view list of students (each student is assigned with a unique memberId) this is the response from the API and i'm displaying it. Student List contains (studentlist.html ,and studentlist.ts) and on UI there is a edit button associated with each row .so on click of each raw it should show me the details of the student in text fields for editing . edit page contains (editStudent.ts and html file)

Comment: when click event occurs the id should be passed through url and i should be able to fetch that id in that page.. can u help me with this @Jared

Comment: In your student listings make the buttons route to your edit details page passing in their member IDs like so: `<button [routerLink]="['/edit-student-details', memberId]">Edit</button>`

Comment: can i move this discussion to chat??/ @Jared

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158573/discussion-between-jared-and-deepak-vijay).

Answer (score 2):

Import ActivatedRoute from @angular/router

```
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
```

Access parameter from constructor:

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    let id = +this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
    // use the id here
}
```